# Feast Your Eyes on a Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry, affix-riddle

Currently working on my fourth anagram puzzle, so in the meantime, I have made a Riley Riddle. Sorry if this riddle seems rather lazy or if the title appears subjective (depending on whether you like Riley Riddles or not — I know I do!).

> My prefix needs a shovel.
>
> My suffix ends a night.
>
> My infix tops a bottle.
>
> From a flight, I'm a delight.

**What am I?**

The title is a clue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you a

> HOLIDAY?

My prefix needs a shovel.

> A HOLE needs a shovel.

My suffix ends a night.

> A DAY ends a night.

My infix tops a bottle.

> A LID tops a bottle.

From a flight, I'm a delight.

> HOLIDAYS are a delight, especially when you take a flight to get there.

Title:

> Feasts are associated with HOLIDAYS.

Comment: Yup — it was a lazy riddle... :P

Comment: That's okay, I'm looking forward to your next anagram one! Those have been awesome! :D

Comment: I guess you in**clu**ded the *clue* in the title as well :D

Comment: Haha that's a terrible pun, but I love it! :P

Comment: I had to add something a lil extra, heheh. I have reached my daily voting limit, so I have to wait $11$ hours before I can upvote. Once I upvote your answer, you will get the tick... or maybe I can just give you the tick right away. I mean, my Riley Riddle is pretty obvious anyway :P

Comment: Well, congratulations! $\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$