# These Riddles Again?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, affix-riddle

> With the beginning, I can make you totally emotionless
>
> Add a few letters to it and you can even find a special kind of school
>
> In the middle, a special kind of energy awaits you
>
> Something that flows in every living thing, they say
>
> The ending is quite a short one
>
> But it is actually what you do to this riddle

What am I?

Hint (Usefulness Level : 0)

> This word is not commonly used in daily conversations

Hint (Usefulness Level : 1)

> This word consists of 13 letters

Hint (Usefulness Level : 1 again)

> You need to use mathematics when doing (The word)

Hint (Usefulness Level : 2)

> The special school in the second line was created a very long time ago (BC)

Hint (Usefulness Level : 2)

> The word is actually a part of a subject at school

Hint (Usefulness Level : 2)

> What I meant by few letters in the second line was **3 letters exactly**

Note :

> Will add more hints if no one gets it after a while

Comment: I think you like Riley riddles a lot

Comment: Maybe I might make a Riley Riddle, too. [My most recent one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70443/feast-your-eyes-on-a-riley-riddle) is admittedly pretty lazy, so I might just make a better one to make up for it :)

Comment: @u_ndefined yep I do :)

Comment: @user477343 u should make one too :) Lots of fun :D

Comment: I will post one very shortly... perhaps $5$ minutes (max) :D

Comment: @user477343 Will look forward to that :)

Comment: Aaaaaand, done! :P

Comment: The middle sounds like qi

Comment: Hmm, you may be right and you may be wrong  :) @Duck

Comment: Ok, that always means yes :)

Comment: Is the prefix the full name of the special school or just part of it?

Comment: Well, from the prefix (It's the prefix right since it's the beginning) you add just a few letters and it becomes a school. Will edit my post @PerpetualJ

Comment: Hrmmmmm just out of curiosity can we get a century or country of origin on the school or will that give it away too easily? Did a search on old schools and there are hundreds.

Comment: ok will do that :) @PerpetualJ

Comment: Well, that didn’t help either haha gonna keep digging, solid schools are recorded with names to the sixth century, everything before that is mostly focused on biblical teachings and there aren’t very many names, maybe with luck I can narrow it down lol

Comment: Yea, I didn't want to make the riddle too easy but will add another hint tomorrow:)

Comment: Any new hints coming today? Hoping to solve this one as I feel like I'm getting close.

Comment: Hmm, I'll probably add one after this :) @PerpetualJ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I may be getting somewhere here :)

> Stoichiometry

Prefix:

> Stoic (emotionless) and stoicism (the school)

Infix (thanks to @Duck and @PerpetualJ):

> Chi

Suffix

> Try (what you do to this riddle)

All the hints add up as well

> 13 letters, involves math, is part of a subject (chemistry), three letters to turn stoic in stoicism

Comment: Congratulations, you are ABSOLUTELY correct. :) You know what, I'm gonna wait a few days (Maybe tomorrow?) then accept and give u the bounty :D

Comment: Yesss! @KevinL up to you I guess. Maybe wait a bit so more people can see the puzzle?

Comment: Yep, will do so :)

Comment: Well, congrats mate :D

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> Resolving

With the beginning, I can make you totally emotionless

> Resolve, a strong resolve can make you hard to sway

In the middle, a special kind of energy awaits you

> Sol, short for solar energy

Last but not least, the ending is what you are doing to this riddle (I guess)

> Solving!

Comment: sorry wrong answer mate :) Gonna add a hint

Comment: I think the first one was kind of a stretch and the last part was half correct (find another word that has similar meaning for the ending part. Nevertheless, nice answer :D

Comment: Hmmm, let's see what we can do here

Comment: @KevinL is the last part rot13(qrpvcure) ?

Comment: Sorry but that's wrong :)

Comment: I'll wait for a hint XD

Comment: Very well, will add one shortly :)

Comment: Thanks. Gave it an upvote so more people can look into it

Comment: Thank you, I'll probably add another hint tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I know this is an incredibly off the wall shot here, but....

> Chuanqiandian? - Relating to the West Hmongic branch of the Miao languages.

*special kind of school - make you emotionless*

> Chuan (pronounced QUAN, 拳) is used to identify schools of Chinese martial arts.

*a special kind of energy awaits you - flows in every living thing*

> Qi (variant spelling of chi) - vital energy that is held to animate the body internally. However, I believe the true infix is going to be *chi*.

*a short one - what you do to this riddle*

> Diǎn (典) - to be in charge of. I am in charge of this riddle. :D Gave me a good laugh anyways.

*Hint 1*

> I have never actually seen, spoke, or heard of this word. :)

*Hint 2*

> Is only 13 letters long.

Comment: The wikipedia page of Chi redirects to Qi, so I think you're right there (maybe it's the more common spelling?). (But I do agree, if I were to say, Chi, I'd probably use Chi or Ki).

Comment: Did you take it from my comment (the qi part)

Comment: The energy part is correct but the others are not

Comment: Is it my first or second guess on the infix?

Comment: The Qi part although the other word was what I meant (Chi) @PerpetualJ. Btw, should I add another hint?

Comment: I would like to say yes, because I’m stuck too. I posted this answer because it made me laugh. Adding another hint is up to you; but I would love one!

Comment: @PerpetualJ Yup just added one. I might have made this riddle a little too difficult :)

Comment: Also regarding Hint 3, the word includes Rot13(puv), which could represent the letter $\chi$ in Greek, and which (ROT13) vf nyfb eryngrq gb zngurzngvpf nf gur terrx nycunorg vf hfrq dhvgr bsgra va vg.

Comment: That would be not only mean, but really clever!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably wrong, but

> Are you reinforcement?

With the beginning, I was made into a special kind of school

But I can still totally make you emotionless

> Rein referring to reining in your horse, so like an equestrian school. The second part refers to reining in your passions, which means to hide your emotions.

n the middle, a special kind of energy awaits you

Something that flows in every living thing, they say

> The force, as Yoda says, "Life creates it, makes it grow. Its energy surrounds us and binds us. Luminous beings are we, not this crude matter."

The ending is quite a short one

But it is actually what you do to this riddle

> Cement. We are trying to cement our answers?

Hint 1:

> It's not really a word you use regularly unless you're playing DnD or in Construction.

Hint 2:

> Reinforcement is 13 letters long.

Comment: Unfortunately you're incorrect :). Just added a hint :)